# Taking the limit $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{\|f\|_\infty}{\|f\|_p}\right)^p$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Taking the limit 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{\|f\|_\infty}{\|f\|_p}\right)^p$$

First I think the expression after taking the limit will depend on the function $f$.

In my attempt, because it is in the form $``1^\infty"$, I tried to use L'Hopital's rule. And we can calculate the limit (assuming the integrals are defined and finite, I just want to see what the limit might look like). 
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\|\nabla u \|_\infty}{\|\nabla u\|_p}\right)^{p} &=  \lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( p\log\left(\frac{\|\nabla u \|_\infty}{\|\nabla u\|_p}\right)\right)\\
&=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( \frac{\log\left(\frac{\|\nabla u \|_\infty}{\|\nabla u\|_p}\right)}{\frac{1}{p}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( \frac{\frac{d}{dp} \left[-\log\left(\frac{\|\nabla u \|_p}{\|\nabla u\|_\infty}\right)\right]}{\frac{-1}{p^2}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \exp\left( \frac{\left(\frac{\|\nabla u \|_\infty}{\|\nabla u\|_p}\right)\frac{\frac{d}{dp}\left[\|\nabla u\|_p \right]}{\|\nabla u \|_\infty}\}}{\frac{1}{p^2}}\right)\\
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dp}\left[\|\nabla u\|_p \right]  &= \frac{d}{dp}\left[\left(\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx \right)^{1/p} \right] \\
&=\frac{d}{dp}\left[\exp\left(\frac{1}{p} \log\left(\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx \right)\right)\right] \\
&=\|\nabla u \|_p \left\{\frac{-1}{p^2}\log\left(\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx \right) + \frac{1}{p} \frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx }\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u|^p \log(|\nabla u |) dx  \right\}
\end{align*}

Putting it back into the limit we get 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \exp \left(-\log\left(\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx \right) + p \frac{1}{\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx }\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u|^p \log(|\nabla u |) dx \right)$$
which simplifies to 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\exp \left(p\frac{\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u|^p \log(|\nabla u |) dx}{\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx } \right)}{\int_{\mathbb R^N} |\nabla u |^p dx }$$

And I am stuck. Is this a correct approach?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think your original instinct is right. Consider $L^p[0,1]$. Then the limit for $f(x) = x$ is $\infty$; the limit for $f(x) = 1$ is $1$; and the limit for $f(x) = 1 + x$ is zero. So given that, it seems unlikely to me that there will be a simplier expression for that limit.

Comment: Try using $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+\frac1n)^n=e$

Comment: @user229922 : You mean $(1+1/n)^n$? ;)

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Yes. So sorry

Comment: @SimonS For the case $f(x) = x+1,$ the limit is $\infty.$

Comment: @zhw, you're quite right. I should have written it down. For the record: if $f(x) = x+ 1$, $\| f \|_\infty = 2$ and $\| f \|_p = \left(\frac{2^{p+1} - 1}{1+p}\right)^{1/p}$ thus 
$$\lim_{p\to\infty} \left( \frac{ \| f \|_\infty}{\| f \|_p}\right)^p = \lim_{p\to\infty} \frac{2^p(1+p)}{2^{p+1}-1} = \infty$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $f\in L^\infty([0,1])$ and $\|f\|_\infty> 0$. Let $E = \{x:|f(x)|=\|f\|_\infty\}.$ Then

$$\lim_{p\to \infty} \left( \frac{\|f\|_\infty}{\|f\|_p}\right)^p = \frac{1}{m(E)}.$$

(If $m(E)=0,$ the conclusion is that the limit is $\infty.$)

Proof: Let $M= \|f\|_\infty$. Then the expression equals

$$\frac{M^p}{M^p\cdot m(E) + M^p\int_{[0,1]\setminus E}|f/M|^p}.$$

Cancel the $M^p$ terms and then apply the dominated convergence theorem to see the integral in the denominator $\to 0.$ That gives the result.

Comment: Nice answer and a nice result!

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I feel like this result depends on the fact that the domain is $[0,1]$ therefore we always have $\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: Well it would work the same on any set of finite measure. In fact, it should work on any measurable set $A$ with one small difference. Let $E$ be as above. If $m(E) = \infty,$ then $\|f\|_p = \infty, 0<p<\infty,$ and all the quotients are $0.$ If $m(E) <\infty,$ then the proof should work as before and the answer should be $1/m(E).$

Comment: I know this is an older posted, but do you think this is related to something that I asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733478/rate-of-convegence-of-lim-n-to-infty-frace2xn-exn-1-exn1