# Rate of convegence of $\frac{E^2[X^n]}{ E[X^{n-1}] E[X^{n+1}]}$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $X$ be a non-negative discrete random variable such that $0\le X\le B$ and$$f(n)=\frac{E^2[X^n]}{E[X^{n-1}]E[X^{n+1}]}$$for $n \ge 1$.

I am interested in the rate of growth of $f(n)$ as $n \to \infty$. In other words, is there a way to quantify how fast $f(n)$ approaches its limit as a function of $n$ and some “property” of $X$?

A few observations:

1. Upper bound: By Cauchy-Schwarz we have that $f(n) \le 1$.
2. Exact limit: It can be shown that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(n)=1$. So, we are trying to refine this limit.
3. Trivial example: If $X$ is supported on $\{0,B\}$, then  $f(n)= 1$ for all $n \ge 1$.
4. Connection to Strong Cauchy-Schwarz: Essentially, this is a question about the sharper versions of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Therefore, using the expression for the correction term in Cauchy-Schwartz we have
   $$
   f(n)=1-\frac{1}{2} E \left[ \left| \frac{X^\frac{n-1}{2}}{ \sqrt{E[X^{n-1}]}}  -\frac{X^\frac{n+1}{2}}{ \sqrt{E[X^{n+1}]}}\right|^2 \right]. 
   $$

I would like to answer this with minimal assumptions, but, if needed, we can assume there is a mass at $B$.

Comment: Did you get something for simple case $P(a)=p, p(b) = q = 1-p$?

Comment: @RiverLi   Nothing other than the trivial $f(n) =\frac{ (pa^n + q b^n)^2}{ (pa^{n-1} + q b^{n-1})  (pa^{n+1} + q b^{n+1}) }$. I only played with this case when $a=0$ in which case $f(n)=1$.    I was focusing more on the general case. I guess I should have.

Comment: Yes, consider $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_m$ with $P(a_1) = p_1, P(a_2) = p_2, \cdots, P(a_m) = p_m$. You will get something like $f(n) = \frac{(1+A)^2}{(1+B)(1+C)}$ with $A, B, C \to 0$. Taylor expansion may be helpful.

Comment: @RiverLi Ok. I tried doing the general case with $m$ points but get stuck all the time. It does appear that Taylor expansion needs to be done, but it gets very messy.  Do you see a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out Problem 7.2 in Steele's *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*. I'll write the statement of this problem:

> Show that if $f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ is a continuous nonincreasing function which is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$, then for any pair of parameters $0 < \alpha, \beta < \infty$, the integral
> \begin{align*}
> I = \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha + \beta} f(x) dx
> \end{align*}
> satisfies the bound
> \begin{align*}
> I^2 \le \left\{1 - \left(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{\alpha + \beta + 1}\right)^2\right\}\int_0^\infty x^{2\alpha} f(x) dx\int_0^\infty x^{2\beta} f(x) dx
> \end{align*}

Yes, this problem technically deals with continuous distributions and assumes a nonincreasing density function $f$. But looking through the proof in the book, I fail to see why we need $f$ to be nonincreasing; it seems that $\int_0^\infty x^{2\max(\alpha, \beta)} f(x) dx < \infty$ is enough from my reading of Steele's proof. Assuming that this problem passes onto the discrete case, we can let $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}(n-1), \beta = \frac{1}{2}(n+1)$ to achieve
\begin{align*}
\frac{E^2[X^n]}{ E[X^{n-1}] E[X^{n+1}]} \le 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the ratio approaches 1 at a rate that is at least (EDIT: thanks to River Li, it should be "at most") quadratic in $n$.

Comment: Thanks much! Let me take a look.

Comment: The proof in the book use integration by parts. But we have a discrete distribution, so we cannot do integration by parts, right?

Comment: You can try using summation by parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Note that for r.v. supported on $\{0,B\}$ we have that $f(n)=1$, so there is a bug somewhere.

Comment: @TomChen  About the assumption of $f(x)$ being non-increasing, please see (7.5) in the book. Indeed,
by using integration by parts, we have
$$\int_0^\infty x^\gamma f(x) \mathrm{d} x
=  - \frac{1}{1+\gamma}\int_0^\infty x^{1+\gamma} f'(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$
Since $f(x)$ is non-increasing, we have $f'(x)\le 0$ and $-f'(x) = |f'(x)|$.
Then we get (7.5).

Comment: @TomChen I think that you can not apply the theorem since $f$ needs  to be non-increasing. That's why your result contradicts $f(n)=1$ when the support is $\{0, B\}$.

Comment: @RiverLi Ah, I missed that portion. This is a great point, but I think perhaps the inequality holds with nonincreasing PMFs then? Because without any other restrictions, Boby's question can't obtain any sharper bounds other than just 1.

Comment: @TomChen  Even you get $f(n) \le 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, how can you say $f(n)$ approaches $1$ at a rate that is at least quadratic in $n$? Since $f(n) \le 1$ by C-S, unless you get $f(n) \ge 1 -  \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, you can say that, right?

Comment: @RiverLi Sorry, a rate that is at most $n^{-2}$ in the sense that $|f(x) - 1| \le (n+1)^{-2} = O(n^{-2})$, but sometimes the terminology switches and we talk with respect to the reciprocal.

Comment: @TomChen I think that if we get $1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < f(n) \le 1$, we can say $f(n)$ approaches $1$ at least quadratic in $n$. But if we get $f(n) < 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, we can not reach the statement, right?

Comment: @TomChen For example, $f(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{\ln \ln n} < 1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$, 
we can not say $f(n)$ approaches $1$ at a rate at least quadratic in $n$.

Comment: @RiverLi You are absolutely right, I've edited my post to reflect your change, and gave you credit there!

Comment: @TomChen  Did you see the other answers. It holds that $1 - c*r^{n-1} < f(n) \le 1$ as $n\to \infty$ where $0 < r < 1$. $f(n)$ approaches $1$ very fast when $r$ is small. Your last estimate contradicts the other answers. Also, as Body pointed out in previous comment, your last estimate contradicts the result when the support is $\{0, B\}$.

Comment: A new challenge if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742664/if-x-le-b-how-refine-the-bound-fracexn1exn-le-b

Answer (score 1):

*Some idea*

Let $m\ge 2$. Let $0 \le a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_m$ and $\mathrm{Pr}(a_1) = p_1, \mathrm{Pr}(a_2) = p_2, \cdots, \mathrm{Pr}(a_m) = p_m$ with $p_1+p_2+\cdots + p_m = 1$. We have
$$f(n) = \frac{(1+A)^2}{(1+B)(1+C)}$$
where
\begin{align}
A = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_j^n}{p_m a_m^n}, \
B = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_j^{n-1}}{p_m a_m^{n-1}}, \
C = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_j^{n+1}}{p_m a_m^{n+1}}.
\end{align}
To proceed, we need the following result. The proof is given at the end.

*Fact 1*: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ and $yz \ge x^2$. Then
$$\frac{(1+x)^2}{(1+y)(1+z)} \ge 1 - (y + z - 2x).$$

Let us proceed. By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have $BC \ge A^2$. By Fact 1, we have
$$1 - (B + C - 2A) \le f(n) \le 1$$
that is
$$1 - \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_j^{n-1}(a_m - a_j)^2 }{p_m a_m^{n+1}}
\le f(n) \le 1.  \tag{1}$$
Remark: Actually, $1 - (B + C - 2A)$ is the Taylor expansion of $\frac{(1+A)^2}{(1+B)(1+C)}$ around $A=0, B=0, C=0$.

We have
\begin{align}
1 - \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_j^{n-1}(a_m - a_j)^2 }{p_m a_m^{n+1}}
&\ge 1 - \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{m-1} p_j a_{m-1}^{n-1}(a_m - 0)^2 }{p_m a_m^{n+1}}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1-p_m}{p_m} \left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m}\right)^{n-1}.
\end{align}
Thus, we have
$$1 - \frac{1-p_m}{p_m} \left(\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m}\right)^{n-1} \le f(n) \le 1. \tag{2}$$

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: After clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that
$$(y+z + yz - x)^2 - yz (1+y)(1+z) \ge 0.$$
From $yz \ge x^2$, we have $y + z \ge 2\sqrt{yz} \ge 2x$ and thus $0 \le y + z + yz - \sqrt{yz} \le y + z + yz - x$.
It suffices to prove that
$$(y+z + yz - \sqrt{yz})^2 - yz (1+y)(1+z) \ge 0$$
or
$$(y+z + yz)(\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{z})^2 \ge 0.$$
It is true. We are done.

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely in the direction of what I was looking for.

Comment: @Boby  I updated my answer a little bit.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look

Comment: What is interesting about this proof is that you use Cauchy-Schwaz (CS) to show a reverse CS.

Comment: I am trying to verify the proof of Fact 1. Can you tell me you go from the second to last equation to the last equation?

Comment: $(y+z + yz - \sqrt{yz})^2 - yz (1+y)(1+z)
= (y+z + yz)^2 - 2(y+z+yz)\sqrt{yz} + yz - yz(1 + y + z + yz)
= (y+z + yz)^2 - 2(y+z+yz)\sqrt{yz} - yz(y + z + yz)
= (y+z+yz)(y+z + yz - 2\sqrt{yz} - yz)
= (y+z+yz)(y + z - 2\sqrt{yz})$

Comment: A new challenge if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742664/if-x-le-b-how-refine-the-bound-fracexn1exn-le-b

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$If $X$ only assumes finitely many values but at least $2$ distinct values, suppose$$
\supp(X) = \{x_1 > \cdots > x_N \geqslant 0\}, \quad p_k := P(X = x_k) > 0 \quad (1 \leqslant k \leqslant N),
$$
then there is the following estimate:

> \begin{gather*}
> \frac{E(X^{n + 1}) E(X^{n - 1})}{(E(X^n))^2} - 1 \sim \frac{p_2}{p_1} \left( 1 - \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right)^2 \left( \frac{x_2}{x_1} \right)^{n - 1} \quad (n → ∞). \tag{1}
> \end{gather*}

*Proof:* Since $E(X^m) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N p_k x_k^m$ for any $m > 0$, then\begin{gather*}
E(X^n) = \sum_{k = 1}^N p_k x_k^n = p_1 x_1^n \left( 1 + \sum_{k = 2}^N \frac{p_k}{p_1} \left( \frac{x_k}{x_1} \right)^n \right) \sim p_1 x_1^n \quad (n → ∞). \tag{2}
\end{gather*}
Note that\begin{align*}
&\peq E(X^{n + 1}) E(X^{n - 1}) - (E(X^n))^2\\
&= \left( \sum_{k = 1}^N p_k x_k^{n + 1} \right) \left( \sum_{k = 1}^N p_k x_k^{n - 1} \right) - \left( \sum_{k = 1}^N p_k x_k^n \right)^2\\
&= \biggl( p_1^2 x_1^{2n} + p_1 p_2 (x_1^{n + 1} x_2^{n - 1} + x_1^{n - 1} x_2^{n + 1}) + \sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant k, j \leqslant N\\(k, j) \not\in \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}}} p_k p_j x_k^{n + 1} x_j^{n - 1} \biggr)\\
&\peq - \biggl( p_1^2 x_1^{2n} + 2p_1 p_2 x_1^n x_2^n + \sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant k, j \leqslant N\\(k, j) \not\in \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}}} p_k p_j x_k^n x_j^n \biggr)\\
&= p_1 p_2 (x_1 - x_2)^2 x_1^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1} + \sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant k, j \leqslant N\\(k, j) \not\in \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}}} p_k p_j (x_k^{n + 1} x_j^{n - 1} - x_k^n x_j^n).
\end{align*}
If $x_2 = 0$, then $N = 2$ and$$
\sum_{\substack{1 \leqslant k, j \leqslant N\\(k, j) \not\in \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}}} p_k p_j (x_k^{n + 1} x_j^{n - 1} - x_k^n x_j^n) = p_2^2 (x_2^{n + 1} x_2^{n - 1} - x_2^{2n}) = 0.
$$
Otherwise for $1 \leqslant k, j \leqslant N$ with $(k, j) \not\in \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)\}$,\begin{gather*}
\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{x_k^{n + 1} x_j^{n - 1}}{x_1^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1}} = x_k^2 \lim_{n → ∞} \left( \frac{x_k x_j}{x_1 x_2} \right)^{n - 1} = 0,\\
\lim_{n → ∞} \frac{x_k^n x_j^n}{x_1^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1}} = x_k x_j \lim_{n → ∞} \left( \frac{x_k x_j}{x_1 x_2} \right)^{n - 1} = 0.
\end{gather*}
Therefore$$
E(X^{n + 1}) E(X^{n - 1}) - (E(X^n))^2 \sim p_1 p_2 (x_1 - x_2)^2 x_1^{n - 1} x_2^{n - 1} \quad (n → ∞),
$$
and combining with (2) yields (1).

Comment: A new challenge if you are interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742664/if-x-le-b-how-refine-the-bound-fracexn1exn-le-b